# Using Pointers to Return a Value - Program Crashes

Tags: c++, pointers, crash

I am new to C++ and experimenting with using pointers to return a values. I have written up a simple program, but I cannot understand why it crashes.

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    bool *pMyBool;

    bar myBar;
    myBar.foo(pMyBool);

    cout << *pMyBool << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

bar.cpp

```
int bar::foo(bool *pMyBool) {
    bool myBool = true;
    *pMyBool = myBool;
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
1
//then it crashes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, you don't want to use pointers in your case, but to use *references*:

```
int bar::foo(bool &MyBool) {
   MyBool = true;
   return 0;
}
```

Of course, you'll just call from your `main`

```
   bool MyMainBool = false;
   bar.foo(MyMainBool);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't initialize `pMyBool` in `main()`, so it points at random memory, and then the program crashes because the random memory isn't valid memory.

One possible fix:

```
int main() {
    bool  value;
    bool *pMyBool = &value;

    bar myBar;
    myBar.foo(pMyBool);

    cout << *pMyBool << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With pointers, you *always* need to ensure you initialize them to point somewhere before you try using them.  **Always!**

Answer (score 2):

`pMyBool` is not pointing to any valid location. SO you cannot dereference it.
You should first allocate memory, and make the pointer, point to it. `bool *pMyBool = new bool;`
and later deallocate memory. `delete pMyBool;`

Answer (score -1):

it's because myBool is allocated in the "stack" (local variables); when the function foo exits, the stack associated with foo is released therefore the pointer pMyBool is pointing to a memory address that is no longer valid.

Comment: After taking a second look, actually, this is the wrong reason why the program crashes.

Comment: This is not the trouble.  It is assigning a (copy of a) local value to the variable pointed to by the parameter, but the parameter is not initialized to point somewhere valid.